# Regular expression to remove all punctuation except commas in regex awk

Tags: shell, awk, regular-expression

I have a variable

```
 local= "[  'service center','New'  ]"
```

I have used the following awk code to remove the square braces and single quotes,

```
 local=gensub(/[\[\]']+/, "", "g", local);
```

Expected O/P is

```
local ="  service center,New  "
```

The code I wrote is not working

Comment: Please provide some more context. I think you might better of using a json parser instead of trying to remove characters from your string. And please fix your code as it's not valid.

Comment: Can you see my updated question

Comment: Still no context. And if it's all inside `awk`, you might want to remove the `shell` tag from the question.

Comment: What exactly is not working. The AWK substitution `local=gensub(/[\[\]']+/, "", "g", local);` produces exactly the expected value. The expression `/[^,[:punct:][:space:]]/` you removed with your edit does not match "(`[:punct:]` or `[:space:]`) and not `,`" but "not (`[:punct:]` or `[:space:]` or `,`)".

Comment: @mittu Works for me. I think you should [edit] your question to include a complete, piece of awk code that exhibits the issue so any readers can repeat it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace commas with a non-punctuation character, remove all remaining puctuation, then restore the commas:

```
awk -v  local="[  'service center','New'  ]" '
  BEGIN {
    gsub(/,/, SUBSEP, local)
    gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, "", local)
    gsub(SUBSEP, ",", local)
    printf("local=\"%s\"\n", local)
  }'
```

```
local="  service center,New  "
```

Here, I'm using the builtin SUBSEP variable, described in [the GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multidimensional.html) thusly:

> The default value of `SUBSEP` is the string `"\034"`, which contains a nonprinting character that is unlikely to appear in an awk program or in most input data

Answer (score 1):

Please find below command and it worked fine

```
cat filename
local= "[  'service center','New'  ]"

sed "s/[^a-zA-Z,= \" ]//g"  filename
output: local= "  service center,New  "


Command:  sed "s/[^a-zA-Z,= \" ]//g" filename
```